# import a class from another file to the class of the main file

Tags: python, tkinter, import

I have a command in create_books, as in the command to call a function from the book1 file and apply it in create_books

```
from book1 import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo, showerror

class Book:
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = tk.Tk()
        self.win.title('Записная книга')
        self.win.geometry("503x150")
 
        self.build_main_window()
        self.win.mainloop()

    def build_main_window(self):
        self.create_title()
        self.create_books()
        self.read_books()
        self.delete_books()
        self.add_books()

    def create_title(self):
        title = tk.Label(self.win, text='Записная книга', font='Arial 16 bold')
        title.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=20, pady=20, sticky='ew')
 
    def create_books(self):
        self.create_but = tk.Button(self.win, text='Добавить запись', command=self.create_books_fun)#this should be called from book1, def create_books_fun
        self.create_but.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=10)
```

book1

```
class CRUD:
    def create_books_fun():
        pass
```

I'm using python 3.11.4

I tried to question artificial intelligence, but it didn't help me in any way

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include more information on what specific errors / issues you're encountering. If you're seeing an error, please include the full error traceback in the body of your question.

Comment: `CRUD.create_books_fun` ?

Comment: Since `create_books_fun` doesn't have a `self` parameter, it should use the `@staticmethod` decorator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `create_books` method inside the `Book` class with:

```py
    def create_books(self):
        self.create_but = tk.Button(self.win, text='Добавить запись', command=CRUD.create_books_fun)
        self.create_but.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=10)
```

Inside CRUD, the method is a static method; You should use the appropriate decorator:

```py
class CRUD:
    @staticmethod
    def create_books_fun():
        pass
```

Also it is better to be explicit in your imports:

```py
from book1 import CRUD
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it solved my problem. I'm going to do additional functions in class CRUD, should I add @staticmethod before every next function?

Comment: You only add `@staticmethod` when your method is not using the `self` parameter